# will my app running without issue if it is used for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in iOS development, and I will deploy the app to the app store. but currently apple has released iOS 13, and unfortunately I just have iPhone 6 that doesn't get the iOS 13 update.

currently I am using Xcode 10.2.1 and my deployment target is 11.0. I don't want to update my Xcode at the moment because I probably need some changes to my app. after I publish the app then I will update the Xcode.

so my question is....
will my app running without issue if it is used for iOS 13 ? because at the moment I can't test it. and the second question is ....

will apple reject my app because of this issue ?

need your information from you

Comment: No one can answer your question. Your app may work or it may not. Only testing on a device with iOS 13 can answer the question. It all depends on your app and your code.

Comment: Almost every app broke visually because of dark mode in dark mode. I personally disabled the dark mode for my apps till the time to update but you **MUST** test.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini visually broke ? but it doesn't crash right ? yes I will try to test it first

Comment: There is a common crash duo accessing `statusBar` in iOS 13. I did't see any other *crash* caused by updating the iOS but I should say again: You must test, **A LOT**

Answer (score 0):

Your app will work properly without any issue if build uploaded by XCode 10.1/10.2.
Uploaded build using Xcode 11 then will be getting issue when device dark mode is ON.
if You are using SearchbarDisplayController in your app then app will get crash.
else app will working fine.
Existing build will not get any issues for iOS 13 and later.